# Keystone JS disable creating new item if it exsist in db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, keystonejs

I am using keystone js and i have session feild that contains 
day and stage should be unique

```
    keystone.createList('Stage', {
  fields: {
    name: {
      type: Text
    }
  }
});
keystone.createList('Day', {
  labelResolver: day => day.day,
  fields: {
    day: {
      label: 'Session Day',
      type: CalendarDay,
      format: 'Do MMMM YYYY',
      defaultValue: Date.now()
    }
  },
  schemaDoc: 'Session Day Date'
});
keystone.createList('Session', {
  labelResolver: () => 'Session',

  fields: {
    day: {
      type: Relationship,
      ref: 'Day',
      isRequired: true,
      isUnique: true,

    },
    stage: {
      type: Relationship,
      ref: 'Stage',
      many: false,
      isRequired: true,
      isUnique: true,
      hooks: {
        beforeChange: async () => { 

         },
      }
    }
  }
```

});

Sessions day & stage should be unique if i created them once i shouldn't be able to create them again.

for example if i have {day: 2020-03-09, stage: Venture} i should't be able to create the same day & stage again because they already exists in the DB.

but i can create {day: 2020-03-09, stage: Miracle}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongodb as backend you can use adapterConfig to do this

```js
keystone.createList('MyList', {
  fields: {
    // other fields 
    day: { /* ... config */},
    stage: { /* ... config */},
  },
  adapterConfig: {
    configureMongooseSchema: (schema) => {
      try {
        schema.index({ day: 1, stage: 1 }, { unique: 1 });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  },
});
```